# Data does not bind with casacading dropdownlist after postback when run on another server

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have three asp.net cascading dropdownlist.one is for selecting topic,2nd is for selecting subtopic and 3rd is for selecting sub-sub-topic.All work fine when it run on local server.But when we run this code on another server then data does not bind with 2nd and 3rd dropdownlist.Plz help me.

# This is my frontend code #

```
<form id="form1" runat="server">
        <div style="padding-left:100px;padding-top:30px;">
           <table align="left" class="auto-style1">
             <tr>
                <td>

                 <table  border="0" class="auto-style3" cellspacing="0"     cellpadding="10" margin-left: "40px">


            <tr>
                <td class="auto-style4">
                    <asp:Label ID="Label2" runat="server" Text="Select Topic" Font-Size="Medium"></asp:Label>
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <asp:DropDownList ID="topicddl1" runat="server" Width="164px" Height="20px" AutoPostBack = "true"
             OnSelectedIndexChanged="topicddl1_SelectedIndexChanged">
               <asp:ListItem Text = "--Select Topic--" Value = ""></asp:ListItem>
                                </asp:DropDownList>



                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td class="auto-style4">
                            Select Subtopic</td>
                        <td>
                            <asp:DropDownList ID="topicddl2" runat="server" Width="164px" Height="20px" AutoPostBack = "True"
             OnSelectedIndexChanged="topicddl2_SelectedIndexChanged">
               <asp:ListItem Text = "--Select Sub-Topic--" Value = ""></asp:ListItem>
                                </asp:DropDownList>

                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td class="auto-style4">
                            Select Sub-Sub Topic</td>
                        <td>
                            <asp:DropDownList ID="topicddl3" runat="server" Width="164px" Height="20px" AutoPostBack = "True"
             OnSelectedIndexChanged="topicddl3_SelectedIndexChanged">
               <asp:ListItem Text = "--Select Sub-Topic--" Value = ""></asp:ListItem>
                                </asp:DropDownList>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
</table>
</div>
</form>

    # This is my backend code #



    public partial class edit : System.Web.UI.Page
    {
        string strcon = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["SPSConnectionString"].ConnectionString;
        SqlDataAdapter da;
        SqlConnection con;
        DataSet ds = new DataSet();
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();
        string qry;
        SqlDataReader dr;
        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (!IsPostBack)
            {
                topicddl1.AppendDataBoundItems = true;
                string strcon = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["SPSConnectionString"].ConnectionString;

                con = new SqlConnection(strcon);

                String strQuery = "select topic_name from topic group by topic_name order by min(sort_id) ";
                SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();
                cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
                cmd.CommandText = strQuery;
                cmd.Connection = con;
                try
                {
                    con.Open();
                    topicddl1.DataSource = cmd.ExecuteReader();
                    topicddl1.DataTextField = "topic_name";
                    topicddl1.DataValueField = "topic_name";
                    topicddl1.DataBind();
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    throw ex;
                }
                finally
                {
                    con.Close();
                    con.Dispose();
                }
            }
        }

        protected void topicddl1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

            topicddl2.Items.Clear();
            topicddl2.Items.Add(new ListItem("--Select Sub-Topic--", ""));
            topicddl3.Items.Clear();
            //'(" + topicddl1.SelectedValue + ")'
            topicddl3.Items.Add(new ListItem("--Select Sub-Sub Topic--", ""));

            topicddl2.AppendDataBoundItems = true;


            con = new SqlConnection(strcon);

            String strQuery = "select sub_topic from topic group by topic_name,sub_topic having  topic_name= '" + topicddl1.SelectedItem.Text + "' order by min(sort_id) ";
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();

            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@topic_name",
                topicddl1.SelectedItem.Value);
            cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
            cmd.CommandText = strQuery;
            cmd.Connection = con;
            try
            {
                con.Open();
                topicddl2.DataSource = cmd.ExecuteReader();
                topicddl2.DataTextField = "sub_topic";

                topicddl2.DataValueField = "sub_topic";
                topicddl2.DataBind();
                if (topicddl2.Items.Count > 1)
                {
                    topicddl2.Enabled = true;
                }
                else
                {
                    topicddl2.Enabled = false;
                    topicddl2.Enabled = false;
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                throw ex;
            }
            finally
            {
                con.Close();
                con.Dispose();
            }


        }

        protected void topicddl2_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

            topicddl3.Items.Clear();
            topicddl3.Items.Add(new ListItem("--Select Sub-Sub-Topic--", ""));
            topicddl3.AppendDataBoundItems = true;
            string strcon = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["SPSConnectionString"].ConnectionString;

            con = new SqlConnection(strcon);

            String strQuery = "select subsub_topic from topic group by sub_topic,subsub_topic having sub_topic='" + topicddl2.SelectedItem.Text + "' order by min(sort_id)";
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();

            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@sub_topic",
                                 topicddl2.SelectedItem.Value);
            cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
            cmd.CommandText = strQuery;
            cmd.Connection = con;
            try
            {
                con.Open();
                topicddl3.DataSource = cmd.ExecuteReader();
                topicddl3.DataTextField = "subsub_topic";

                topicddl3.DataValueField = "subsub_topic";
                topicddl3.DataBind();
                if (topicddl3.Items.Count > 1)
                {
                    topicddl3.Enabled = true;
                }
                else
                {
                    topicddl3.Enabled = false;
                }

            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                throw ex;
            }
            finally
            {
                con.Close();
                con.Dispose();
            }
        }
```

Comment: If you run the queries by themselves on the remote server, do you get the same results as on your local server?

Comment: output is coming in localhost server with same queries but not coming in other server after postback.

Comment: I was wondering if the problem came from the data in the database tables (being different on the remote server). In order to check that, you could test the query on the remote server without using your application.

Comment: query is running in another server..but data is not bind with second dropdownlist.